# カスタムキーボードでUICollectionViewを使いたいが表示されない

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

テスト的に書いたソースです。
表示もされません。どこが悪いのか教えていただけないでしょうか。エラーは出ませんが表示も出ません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

PS:最低限のソースに修正しました。

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

    private var lexicon: UILexicon!
    var myCollectionView : UICollectionView!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Perform custom UI setup here
        self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .System)

        self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), forState: .Normal)
        self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
        self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

        let nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        let nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
        self.view.addConstraints([nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint, nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint])

        // CollectionViewのレイアウトを生成.
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        // サイズの設定
        layout.itemSize.height = 20
        layout.itemSize.width = 100

        // Cell一つ一つの大きさ.
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(10, 10)

        // Cellのマージン.
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 16, 32, 16)

        // セクション毎のヘッダーサイズ.
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(100,30)

        // CollectionViewを生成.
        myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        myCollectionView.frame.size.height = 100
        myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 100
        myCollectionView.frame.offset(dx: 100, dy: 100)

        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        print(myCollectionView.delegate)
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        print(myCollectionView.dataSource)



        // Cellに使われるクラスを登録.
        myCollectionView.registerClass(CustomUICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")

        myCollectionView.sizeToFit()
        print(myCollectionView.frame)


        view.addSubview(myCollectionView)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    }

    override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
        // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
    }

    override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
        // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

        var textColor: UIColor
        let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
        if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
            textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, forState: .Normal)
    }


    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource


    /*
    Cellが選択された際に呼び出される
    */
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")

    }

    /*
    Cellの総数を返す
    */
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    /*
    Cellに値を設定する
    */
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell : CustomUICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomUICollectionViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = indexPath.row.description

        return cell
    }
}

class CustomUICollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell{

    var textLabel : UILabel?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // UILabelを生成.
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height))
        textLabel?.text = "nil"
        textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        // Cellに追加.
        self.contentView.addSubview(textLabel!)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コードを見たところ、`UICollectionView`の使い方や`UIKit`の基本的なプログラミングがいろいろと間違っています。

まず、`myCollectionView`は幅も高さもゼロなので、表示されません。
次に、コレクションビューにデータを表示するためには`delegate`と`detaSource`を設定して、必要なメソッドを実装していく必要がありますが、`self.dele`と`self.collection`はどちらも変数を定義しただけなので、中身がありません（`nil`のままです）

さらに、`delegate`と`detaSource`の各メソッドは`KeyboardViewController`に実装されているので、`KeyboardViewController`のインスタンス（`self`）を設定しなければなりませんが、`self.dele`と`self.collection`を設定しているのは明らかに間違いです。

他にもおかしいところは数多くありますが、とりあえず最初の基本的な使い方を理解してないと思いますので、いきなりキーボードを作る前に本などを見て簡単なプログラムをいくつか書いてみると、わかるようになると思います。

Comment: このプログラムを、キーボード以外で作ると表示されます。違いは、`UICollectionViewDelegate`と`UICollectionViewDataSource`が、キーボード以外では`class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{}`となるだけです。キーボードの場合この指定はエラーですが。という事は、後者の場合、勝手にサイズも中身も設定さているという事でしょうか。

Comment: またlayout.itemSize.height = 20、layout.itemSize.width = 100としていますが、変わりません。

Comment: このプログラムは色んなプログラムを見て、キーボード用に書き換えた練習用に書いたプログラムなんです。だから最低限のコードしか書いていません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 私の回答は読まれましたか？とりあえず、一つ一つ進んでいくしかない思いますので、`myCollectionView.delegate = self.dele`と`myCollectionView.dataSource = self.collection`のところを直しましょう。`self.dele`と`self.collection`には何かオブジェクトが入ってるんですか？`print(self.dele)`と`print(self.collection)`としたら何が出力されますか？

Comment: `pr‌​int(self.dele)`と`print(self.collection)`は確かに、`nil`が出力されます。つまり設定されていないって事ですね。キーボードではないプログラムを参照して潰してみます。

Comment: delgateとcollectionの設定を修正しました。サイズの設定もしてみましたが変化ありません。上記ソースコードも修正しています。すみませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 私の回答を読んでその通りにしてみる気はないのでしょうか？`myCollectionView.sizeToFit()`の前後に`print(myCollectionView.frame)`を書いて、`myCollectionView`のサイズを確かめてみましょう。おそらく`sizeToFit()`は不要です。また、`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` のメソッドでログを出力するかブレークポイントを置くかして、それが呼ばれているかどうかを確認しましょう。

Comment: すみません。ソースに修正が反映されていませんでした。delgateとcollectionは解決したようです。`print(myCollectio‌​nView.frame)`がすべて0なので、ここを修正する必要があるという事ですね。サイズ設定は`myCollectionView.frame.width.distanceTo(100)`ではダメなようですね。サイズの設定方法を調べてみます。

Comment: 一応`myCollectionView.frame.size.height = 100`と `myCollectionView.frame.size.width = 100`　で、なんとか表示できました。あとは表示開始位置の設定の問題ですね。

Comment: `myCollectionView.frame.offset(dx: 100, dy: 100)`で表示開始位置設定できました。あとは横スクロールですが、設問が違うので調べてみてわからなければ別途します。ありがとうございました。